# In a special case, how the copy constructor is called？

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor

I wrote a class in Visual Studio 2017:

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person() {cout << "construtor" << endl; };
    Person(istream&a);
    Person(const Person&a) :name(a.name), address(a.address) { cout << "copy construtor" << endl; }
    ~Person() { cout << "destructor" << endl; };
private:
    string name;
    string address;
}
Person::Person(istream&a)
{
    a >> name >> address;
    cout << "call fuction" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    Person a =Person(cin);
    return 0;
}
```

In my opinions,I think `Person(cin)` may create a temporary obeject;It call Functions`Person(istream&a)`;Then  was `a`created by copy construtor.
So I think the debug results should be like this if I enter `Jack CN`:

```
Jack CN
call fuction
copy constructor
destructor
destructor
```

But the result is amazing actually:

```
Jack CN
call fuction
destructor
```

I have seen that copy initialization happens in
using `=`to define variable in C++ primer.Why it didn't happen here.I am searching for a long time on net. Someone talked to me that `Person a =Person(cin);` equals `Person a(cin)` here;When I debugged,they got the same results.

But I thought of a method.I tried to put `Person(const Person&a) :name(a.name), address(a.address) { cout << "copy construtor" << endl; }` into `private:`.
An amazing things happended.The version of `Person a(cin)` successfully compiled and run.The version of `Person a =Person(cin);`didn't compile;`Person::Person(const Person&a) is Inaccessible`.So if `Person a =Person(cin);` equals `Person a(cin)` here.Why `Person a =Person(cin);`can not be compiled.And if `Person a =Person(cin);` did not call copy construtor.Why when I put it into `private:` ,it went wrong.So I want to know how `a`in `Person a =Person(cin)` is initializated.

Is there some compiler optimization or my opinion is wrong?
 I am searching for a long time. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use a compiler that is a bit more recent, you'll see that even if the copy constructor is private, [it compiles](https://godbolt.org/g/xcq3vU). :)

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely

Comment: @user9127904 -- *In my opinions,I think Person(cin) may create ...* -- You even say it yourself.   You used the word "may", implying that things may be done that way, and maybe not.  It all depends on the compiler and compiler optimizations.

Comment: @Rakete1111 [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) says "When a nameless temporary, not bound to any references,would be copied or moved (since C++11) into an object of the same type",the copy constructor still must be present and **accessible**.So using **private** is ill-formed.

Comment: @bigxiao Jup, that's why I mentioned *newer* compilers :) Well anyways, look at the first paragraph in cppref you quoted. In C++17, prvalues do not create objects, they are just "recipes" that in some cases create objects. That's why it works.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Why does the return value of function still requires **accessible** in c++17? As far as I know,the return value is also prvalue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie c++17 says "If return expression is a prvalue, the object returned by the function is initialized directly by that expression. This does not involve a copy or move constructor when the types match ",what does that mean? Why does it use the term "object"? in c++17 prvalue is not a object any more.